# File upload returns 200 but file not uploaded (express to spring)

Tags: angularjs, spring, express, multipartform-data, ng-file-upload

I am trying to upload a file from my local `uploads` folder to an external web server `(Java Spring)` but I can't seem to get it to work. I am getting a 200 Ok status return but when I check, the file has not been uploaded.

Here is my code for reference:

```
var form = new FormData();

form.append('my_field', 'my value');
form.append('my_buffer', new Buffer(10));
form.append('my_logo', request('http://localhost:8080/' + req.files.file.path));

request({
    url: someDomain + '/proj/new/deliveryAttachment',
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
        'Accept' : 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
    },
    jar: getJar(),
    qs: {
        pid: req.query.id
    },
    formData: {
        deliveryAttachment: form
    }
}, function (error, response, body) {       
    res.send(body);
});
```

And here is the Java Spring controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "proj/new/deliveryAttachment", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE, produces = MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_VALUE)
public String insertDeliveryAttachment(@RequestParam("pid") long pid,
        @RequestParam("deliveryAttachment") MultipartFile file) {
    try {
        DeliveryAttachment a = new DeliveryAttachment(file.getOriginalFilename(), pid);
        ps.insertDeliveryAttachment(a, file.getBytes());
        return String.valueOf(a.id);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        return "-1";
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated!

**EDIT**

I have screencapped the console log and it seems that it can only pass through the middleware API then to the part where it gets the file from the `uploads` folder. It doesn't proceed to the request.post though.

[image]

Comment: From the information shared it's too hard to tell what exactly the issue could be. My suggestion would be to put sufficient loggers and / or debug to see if all steps are executed / parameters have expected value.

Comment: Okay. Will edit post now.

Answer (score 0):

To retrieve file please process like this :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "proj/new/deliveryAttachment", method =RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE, produces = MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_VALUE)
public String insertDeliveryAttachment(@RequestParam("pid") long pid,
    @RequestPart("deliveryAttachment") MultipartFile file) // This is the key annotation to use
{
    //Your code here 
}
```